# VM CPU usage static v. dynamic in Host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

I hope this is a general knowledge question on VM-s.

I have set up a vm to use one core out of four in the host using VirtualBox, and i have noticed the host cpu usage is always above 25%, even if the vm isnt doing anything. Same thing happens with RAM, but I still want to make sure:

Once you allocate certain resources like one core CPU in this case, will that resource be under load all the time ? Is the host consuming electrical power although neither machines (host/vm) are doing anything significant ? Or is this something particular to VirtualBox ?

Edit. Both host and guest run Windows 10 Pro x64, guest reports 3-4% CPU utilization. Power plan in guest is set to Balanced but it never downclocks.  Guest is configured with one core, 2GB RAM and is located on a HDD. **Disk Encryption is enabled in VirtualBox for the guest.** VirtualBoxVM.exe in host stays at a fixed 25% CPU

Comment: What guest OS is running on VirtualBox? What CPU load does the guest itself report? Does it show 100% or is it closer to 0%? Some very old operating systems were not yet able to tell the CPU to "idle" and would busy-loop even when they were functionally doing nothing. (VirtualBox tries to detect such situations for some popular systems e.g. Win9x and replaces them with a true idle state, but e.g. for NetWare you may need VMIDLCPU.NLM or NW5-IDLE.NLM to be loaded, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine product doesn't allocate a physical CPU. The emulated
CPU is just an ordinary process that executes machine code of the VM.
This process is allocated CPU time by the host according to the
operating system's scheduling algorithm, but never a whole core for its
exclusive use.

An operating system is never in a situation that it is "doing nothing".
It's actually always active, with hundreds of background services
doing all sort of jobs, like taking care of the hardware, advancing
the clock etc etc.

Any CPU work uses electrical power, so the host and the VM both will
consume some power all the time, even while idling. To stop using
power, you need to put the host into sleep.

That said, occupying a whole core is a bit extreme.
You should check what's exactly running inside the VM,
and the possibility that the host or VM are infected.

Comment: Even if that's the case, it would not occupy 100% of a core the entire time (that being 25% of OP's host) – something like 2-3% is more typical. Are you saying that all those background services would occupy 100% of the CPU?

Comment: I have no idea what's installed inside the VM.

Comment: @user1686: But I forgot to write the last paragraph...

Comment: @Romen: The host counts real CPU usage, it doesn't know what the VM is doing.

Comment: I have seen some VM hosts actually report a core go "idle", because it knows that the client OS is idle too. If the host doesn't know what the client OS is doing then it would count client idle time as "real CPU usage" because all instructions run by the client are categorically not instructions run by the host's idle service. There are definitely VM hosts that fix this, and I believe it depends on the hardware VM extensions too.